# How can I get the maximum value for Instant#ofEpochSecond(?)

Tags: java, java-time, epoch, java.time.instant

I just found that the `Instant#ofEpochSecond(epochSecond)` has minimum/maximum values.

Here comes the source codes.

```java
// Instant.java
    /**
     * The minimum supported epoch second.
     */
    private static final long MIN_SECOND = -31557014167219200L;
    /**
     * The maximum supported epoch second.
     */
    private static final long MAX_SECOND = 31556889864403199L; // << I WANT THIS VALUE!
```

How can I get the `MAX_SECOND` programmatically?

I tried to figure out with `Range`,

```java
        final var range = ChronoField.INSTANT_SECONDS.range();
        log.debug("        minimum: {}", range.getMinimum());
        log.debug(" largestMinimum: {}", range.getLargestMinimum());
        log.debug("        maximum: {}", range.getMaximum());
        log.debug("smallestMaximum: {}", range.getSmallestMaximum());
```

and has no luck.

```
03:53:36.120 [                main] DEBUG -         minimum: -9223372036854775808
03:53:36.122 [                main] DEBUG -  largestMinimum: -9223372036854775808
03:53:36.122 [                main] DEBUG -         maximum: 9223372036854775807
03:53:36.122 [                main] DEBUG - smallestMaximum: 9223372036854775807
```

Comment: Super curious to why given the date that that number ends up at

Comment: @DarrenForsythe That's `1000000000-12-31T23:59:59Z` anyway. The API designer must be confident a billion years enough.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can get the max/min second like this:

```
import java.time.Instant;


long maxSecond = Instant.MAX.getEpochSecond(); 
long minSecond = Instant.MIN.getEpochSecond();
```